# SQL Server Query never completes when filtered by specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named `inventory_transaction` in a SQL Server 2008 R2 production environment. The table and indexes, as well as the maintenance package to maintain them, were developed by a professional vendor. We have had no problems for almost 10 years since implementing the program that uses this table, and there is no fragmentation above 8% on any of the indexes for the table.

However, I am having some trouble now. When I try to filter this table by one specific value, the query will not complete. Any other value will make the query execute in < 1 sec.

Here is the specific query that will not complete:

```
DECLARE @BASE_ID VARCHAR(30) = 'W46873'    

SELECT * 
FROM PROD.DBO.INVENTORY_TRANS  
WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID = @BASE_ID
```

I let it run for 35 minutes before cancelling it. I never receive an error message. If I put literally any other value in `@BASE_ID`, it will execute in <1 sec. If I change the equal operator on `WORKORDER_BASE_ID` to use `LIKE` and change `@BASE_ID` to `@BASE_ID = 'W4687%'`, it will work. All values in this column are the same format (W + 5 numbers).

The data type for `@BASE_ID` is the same as the column `WORKORDER_BASE_ID` on the table. There is a nonclustered index that includes this column which is being used by in other query plans that are completing for other values. Since this one won't complete, I'm not sure what the actual execution plan it is using is.

Any ideas what could be causing this or what I could do to fix it? I can provide more information as needed. This issue is causing timeouts within the program, which creates a lot of problems.

---

EDIT1:
Running the query with OPTION(RECOMPILE) doesn't help.

```
DECLARE @BASE_ID VARCHAR(30) = 'W46873'    

SELECT * 
FROM VMFGTEST.DBO.INVENTORY_TRANS  
WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID = @BASE_ID
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Is `inventory_trans` a table or a view?  How large is it?

Comment: I would drop and recreate the index.

Comment: It is a table. Data space is ~80MB, index space is ~55MB. Around 350k rows.

Comment: The indexes are rebuilt 3 times a week as part of an automated maintenance plan. Would that not fix it? Like I said, there is hardly any fragmentation on them.

Comment: I would explicitly drop and create the index anyway. Also, did you try running the query with a recompile? "SELECT * 
FROM PROD.DBO.INVENTORY_TRANS  
WHERE WORKORDER_BASE_ID = @BASE_ID option (recompile)"

Comment: Recompile doesn't seem to many any difference. I will try to drop and recreate the index on our test database and see what happens.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I worked with our test database and realized the problem doesn't occur there. Our test database is from last night's backup, so that means the issue developed since then. I'm going to wait for tonight's backup and then update the test database in the morning, then try and drop and recreate the index. Unfortunately, I can't take the production DB offline (in order to prevent users connecting) without being sure it will work. I'll update the question when I have more info.

Comment: 35 mins on a 100mb table sounds like blocking. An uncomiited transaction probably has a lock on one of the rows that predicate value would need to read. Whilst it is hung look in the waiting tasks DMV to see if it is waiting for something and if so what.

Comment: What if you display the estimated execution plan in SSMS? Or there is a query part way down this page which will allow you to extract the query plan from the query plan cache https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Comment: Can you try using no index at all? "select ... from inventory_trans with (index(0)) where ..."

Comment: I’ll try in the morning and post my results. After thinking about it, an uncommitted transaction sounds likely. I’ll check everything and post tomorrow, though. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: 1. Compare query plans between functioning and non functioning; 2.use `sp_who2` (or whatever yout favourite tool is - I like `sp_whoisactive`)  to see if there is blocking

Comment: It was being blocked by another process; thank you everyone for your help. I followed Andrey's answer and found the issue. I'm sure your other comments here would've led me there too, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query may have been blocked by another process. While running your query in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), check the tab title. The parenthesized number at the end is the Server Process ID (SPID):

[image]

While your query is still executing, execute the following command in another window to check if your query is being blocked:

```
/* Replace 70 with actual SPID */
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = 70
```

If the *blocked* column contains a positive number, this is the SPID of the process blocking your query. For more details about this process, execute the following command:

```
/* Replace 62 with the actual SPID of the process in question */
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(62)
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = 62
```

The EventInfo may hint you on what is being executed in this connection, while `login_time`, `hostname`, `program_name` and other columns could pinpoint the connected user. For example another transaction may still be active.

Comment: This was the issue! It was being blocked by another blocked process.... I killed the root process and everything immediately cleared up. Thank you for the clear explanation and instructions! To anyone worrying about me just killing the process, it was hung due to another issue which has been resolved, so it shouldn't happen again.